# Unrecogized selector in libBlocksKit.a

Tags: ios, objective-c

If I used actionsheet functions in UIActionSheet+BlocksKit.h category file in my project then it would be crashed(For example: +[UIActionsheet actionSheetWithTitle:] unrecognized selector). UIActionSheet+BlocksKit.h in the libBlockKit.a library. I'm using [this lib](https://bitbucket.org/nwoolls/simpledrawing/wiki/Home)
Please help me.

Comment: do you import "UIActionSheet+BlocksKit.h" to the file where you're calling methods from this category? Have you linked libBlockKit.a to your project?

Comment: it works perfectly in an another project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `-ObjC` to `Other Linker Flags` (OTHER_LDFLAGS) in Build settings.

See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1490/_index.html